# I have an issue with postgresql, something is preventing the postgres to startup. I cant figure out the solution for this issue

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

I have an issue with postgresql, something is preventing the postgres to startup in the cloud server. I cant figure out the solution for this issue.

here i attached the log file.

```
2021-12-18 10:19:08.928 IST [17910] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2021-12-18 10:19:09.464 IST [17924] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
2021-12-18 10:19:09.896 IST [17910] LOG:  setsockopt(TCP_KEEPIDLE) failed: Invalid argument
2021-12-18 10:19:27.300 IST [17910] LOG:  received smart shutdown request
2021-12-18 10:19:27.309 IST [17910] LOG:  worker process: logical replication launcher (PID 17917) exited with exit code 1
2021-12-18 10:19:27.309 IST [17925] server@database FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
2021-12-18 10:19:27.328 IST [17912] LOG:  shutting down
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Who is your provider? Are you running this on bare metal? A VM? In a container? As part of the cloud provider's own PostgreSQL service? What command is issued to start the server?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be very urgent, but if you're still interested, remove the keepalives_idle parameter if your "server" doesn't support TCP_KEEPIDLE (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/libpq-connect.html).